# Files.isDirectory NullPointerException

Tags: java, nio

I work with the Java FileSystem and i will know is the File a Directory, but i get every time a NullPointerException.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/dev");
System.out.println(Files.isDirecory(path, null);
```

Comment: I hope you do "System.out.println(Files.isDirectory(path, null));" instead of "System.out.println(Files.isDirecory(path, null);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough :

```
System.out.println(Files.isDirectory(path));
```

The second argument is an optional vargs indicating how symbolic links are handled.

Providing it `null` and getting a `NullPointerException` seems related.

Comment: Yea, ok thanks. I have not seen that goes also. But its interesting that if i get a Path from FileSystem `FileSystem.getRootDirectories()` its work.

Answer (score -1):

You have spell error in your code. Here it is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:/dev");
        System.out.println(Files.isDirectory(path, null);
    }
```

You spell wrong `isDirectory`

Comment: I am sure it is a typo, otherwise it would not compile and give a runtime exception. Also you are missing a closing bracket